# easy_install unmet dependencies which already exist

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to use `easy_install` on ubuntu 14-04, but running fails due to a missing dependency on `setuptools 3.3`

```
$ easy_install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/easy_install", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  ...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 839, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'setuptools==3.3' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

If I list what I have installed with `pip`, I can see that I have `setuptools 17.1.1` installed

```
$ pip list | grep setuptools
setuptools (17.1.1)
```

I looked at the source for `easy_install`, and it's really simple.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'setuptools==3.3','console_scripts','easy_install'
__requires__ = 'setuptools==3.3'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('setuptools==3.3', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
    )
```

I then edited the file, and replaced all mentioned of `setuptools==3.3` with `setuptools=17.1.1`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'setuptools==17.1.1','console_scripts','easy_install'
__requires__ = 'setuptools==17.1.1'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('setuptools==17.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
    )
```

It now works - but clearly that doesn't feel like the right way to fix the problem!

### Questions

- Is this a bug with `easy_install`?
- Am I able to upgrade `easy_install` to resolve this?
- When I added the `pip` tag to this question, I see that it's listed as a replacement for `easy_install`. Am I able to replace `easy_install` with `pip` and it should just work?

Comment: I can really only answer the last question but yeah, pip for most intents and purposes should fully replace easy_install.

However, if you need multiple versions of a module (like for testing, and don't want to use virtualenvs), sys.path changes, or some other, unusual support, use easy_install:
https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/pip_easy_install.html

Comment: Also, I looked at the source for a much newer version of easy_install and it seems like each one is bound to a specific version. Upgrading both should fix your dependency issue:
---- Here's mine.

#! /usr/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'setuptools==12.2','console_scripts','easy_install'
__requires__ = 'setuptools==12.2'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('setuptools==12.2', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
    )

Comment: Obviously you have 2 versions of setuptools installed on your machine. One you got from system package manager (http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/trusty/python-setuptools) and another one was installed manually. The latter shadows the former and you get an exception.

Comment: @Alik how do I remove one and leave the other?